# UITableView row count like iOS Mail app

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do you add counts inside of a `UITableView` `UITableViewCell` like the iOS Mail app?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DDBadgeViewCell (mentioned by @micpringle), there's also [TDBadgedCell](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell).

I tried out both and found TDBadgedCell to suit my needs more, as it puts the badges over the cell's text rather than under it, meaning the badges are visible even for cells with long texts.

The project also seems to be (currently, at least) more active than DDBadgeViewCell. (That being said, there seems to be a bug in the non-ARC version of TDBadgedCell.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UITableViewCell, position the labels where you want them (title, subtitle, count, whatever you need). I highly recommend [Matt Gallaghers custom UITableView code](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html) - it takes a lot of the headaches out of dealing with custom rows.  You'll have to follow Matt Gallaghers steps for customizing the cell.

To get the appearance of the count label as close as possible to your example (mail.app), you'll have to set the UILabel backgroundColor to gray (or whatever color you want it to be), textColor to white, and layer.cornerRadius to something equal to half the height of the label (if label is 20 high, cornerRadius should be 10). This will result in a UILabel with white text, gray background, round corners. Note - this isn't the most efficient method of doing this, but Apple hasn't put up the WWDC session video where they explain the performant method better (I missed that session).

Comment: So there's no way to create it programmatically without using something like the link you provided?

Comment: You can add labels programmatically, but it can be a miserable experience. In your -cellForRowAtIndexPath method, when you configure the cell create a UILabel and add it to the cells view.

Comment: So how would you recommend creating that look in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to set an `UILabel` as `accessoryView` or using a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass which could be designed using IB.

I'd recommend creating a simple rounded `UIView` and a `UILabel` as a subview in it. I'd probably create a `UITableViewCell` subclass to manage the content.

Definitively the most easy way would be using a ready-to-use class like [TDBadgedCell](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell)